# Is there a way to parse ElementTree values based on the value of the element?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I am using ElementTree to get the various element tags from some XML returned via `requests` module.  Within the `<callvariables>` tag I have numerous `<CallVariable>` sets.

```
             <callvariables>
                <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable1</name>
                    <value>Client</value>
                </CallVariable>
                <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable2</name>
                    <value>1234567890</value>
                </CallVariable>
                <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable3</name>
                    <value>Illinois</value>
                </CallVariable>
                  ........
```

I can pull all `name` and `value` items from the XML using

```
for child in root.findall('.//CallVariable'):
    name = child.find('.//name')
    value = child.find('.//value')
    print(name.text, value.text)
```

but is there a way to pull the `value` based on the `name`?  For example, searching for `callVariable1` and having it return `Client`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElementTree's [XPath support is limited](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), but it would be simple enough to use a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates) on `CallVariable` to test the value of `name`.

Example...

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
<callvariables>
    <CallVariable>
        <name>callVariable1</name>
        <value>Client</value>
    </CallVariable>
    <CallVariable>
        <name>callVariable2</name>
        <value>1234567890</value>
    </CallVariable>
    <CallVariable>
        <name>callVariable3</name>
        <value>Illinois</value>
    </CallVariable>
</callvariables>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

target_elem = root.find(".//CallVariable[name='callVariable1']/value")

print(target_elem.text)
```

Prints...

```
Client
```

Another example of just modifying your `for` so it's easier to see how you'd just need to add the predicate...

```py
for child in root.findall('.//CallVariable[name="callVariable1"]'):
    name = child.find('name')
    value = child.find('value')
    print(name.text, value.text)
```

Prints...

```
callVariable1 Client
```

Answer (score 1):

For such structure of xml, pandas `read_xml`  is very convenient:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

xml = """
<callvariables>
    <CallVariable>
        <name>callVariable1</name>
        <value>Client</value>
    </CallVariable>
    <CallVariable>
        <name>callVariable2</name>
        <value>1234567890</value>
    </CallVariable>
    <CallVariable>
        <name>callVariable3</name>
        <value>Illinois</value>
    </CallVariable>
</callvariables>
"""

file_name = StringIO(xml)

df = pd.read_xml(file_name, xpath = './CallVariable').query('name == "callVariable1"')
# df = pd.read_xml(file_name, xpath = "./CallVariable[name='callVariable1']")
print(df['value'].to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
Client
```

Comment: @DanielHaley, I have edit my answer to your request, see above.

Answer (score 0):

You could move to `lxml` which has better xpath support

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse("my.xml")
values = doc.xpath(".//CallVariable/name[text()='callVariable1']/../value/text()")
```